# Error "Please insert PRERENDERUNICODE"

Tags: unicode, amsart, input-encodings

I meet a subtle problem. My simplest code is as follows. I am working in Win 7-32bit, my editor is WinEdt 7.0 (Build: 20120125  (v. 7.0)), saved as UTF-8, compiled with `pdflatex`(MiKTeX2.9).

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\title{U}%Ü
\author{ü}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The result is [image], there is error message

```
[PLEASEINSERT\PRERENDERUNICODE{}INTOPREAMBLE]
```

What subtle is if I change `amsart` to `article`, or change the first U to Ü, the problem disappears.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is due to a slight incompatibility of `utf8x` with `amsart` (that capitalizes the author's name).

You have two paths to follow:

1. say `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
2. make the offending character known to `ucs` and `utf8x` before `\begin{document}`

Path 1 is preferable, if you don't use characters that aren't covered by this option (and even if you do, as it's usually easy to add the needed ones).

If you stick with `utf8x`, then say as it's said in quite a cryptic way in the output: add

```
\PrerenderUnicode{ü}
```

in the preamble (after loading `\inputenc`). Add all the accented characters that might offend `ucs` (that's automatically loaded).

Comment: If I do the second option with `è` I get `! Package utf8x Error: MalformedUTF-8sequence.` on those characters.

Comment: @naught101 Then don't use the second option and go with the first.

Comment: I went with the second option because the first wasn't working either. In the end (after 2 days fighting it) I gave up and just replaced all of the special characters with `\'e` etc. I suspect it might have something to do with the American Meteorological Society journal template I had to use.

Comment: @naught101 If so, this warrants a new question.

Answer (score 8):

if you want to use `utf8x` you need to also use `ucs`. However utf8x has not been maintained for a long time and it is much preferable to use `utf8` instead:

simply replace

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

with

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and it will display properly.

Comment: `ucs` is loaded automatically when the `utf8x` option is specified.

Comment: oh so it is. I haven't used utf8x for so long that I can't tend to forget what the issues are.

Comment: if I do that with a `è` character in the document, I get `Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�t� not set up for use with LaTeX.`